# Many to one configuration using EF 4.1 code first

Tags: ef-code-first, many-to-one

I have the following classes:

```
public class CartItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product    {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I currently have the following configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CartItem>().HasRequired(x => x.Product).WithMany().Map(x => x.MapKey("ProductId"));
```

I am trying to ensure that whenever I retrieve a cartitem from the database there will be a join on the product table so I can access the product properties but not the other way around.

I basically want to be able to do:

```
string title = cartItem.Product.Title
```

using the configuration I have gives me an Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: to solve your problem, make the `Product` property `virtual`.

In-depth:

First, you **don't** need a join to do this. EF works fine with lazy loading (you need the `virtual` modifier)

Second, you can fetch the Product eagerly, using the `Include` extension method. Example:

```
var cartItem = context.CartItems.Include(x => x.Product)
                      .Where(/*some condition*/).ToList();
```

...but you can't configure this to be the default behavior (nor is it a good idea usually)

Third, this is a many-to-one relationship, not one-to-one (a Product *has many* related CartItems)