# One to one relation with EF 4.1 code first

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, code-first, one-to-one

My question is similar to this one :

--> [Many to one configuration using EF 4.1 code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845429/one-to-one-configuration-using-ef-4-1-code-first)

There are some fluent API solutions on google, with overriding "OnModelCreating" method and manually setting the foreign key options. But i would prefer a solution with data annotations if it is possible. Because I'd like to use inverse properties while coding. Such as TypeA object has got a TypeB object. So TypeB object should have a ParentTypeA property. Example :

```
public class User : IUser
{
    [Key(), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]{2,32}"), MinLength(2), MaxLength(32)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

   // other props ....
   // ....

    public virtual UserGallery Gallery { get; set; }
}

public class UserGallery : IUserGallery
{
    [Key(), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserGalleryId { get; set; }

   // other props ....
   // ....

    public virtual User ParentUser { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare one to one relationship using Entity Framework 4 Code First (POCO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622572/how-to-declare-one-to-one-relationship-using-entity-framework-4-code-first-poco)

Answer (score 1):

A conventions way to do this in Code First is to use the UserID as the Primary Key of the UserGallery object.  This is fine if its a true one to one relationship.

```
public class UserGallery : IUserGallery
{
   [Key]
   public int UserId {get;set;}
   public User User {get;set;}
   etc...
}
```

This has worked fine for me in the past.

Comment: Strange. I tried again after all this time and it works now :)

Comment: @Michal B are you using the same version of EF as you were then?